# Riehl 2.2 vii: Path functor and Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory

The path functor is defined here: 
[image]

Now, it doesn't mention it, but it seems clear that Path functor would map continuous mapping $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to post composition by $f$.

Now, the problem asks

[image]

Natural automorphisms of the path functor $Path: Top \rightarrow Set$ would be given by

$$\alpha: Path \rightarrow Path$$ such that for topological space $X$, If $g$ is a path in $X$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map,

$$f\alpha_X(g) = \alpha_Y(fg)$$

The book says that this is called re-parametrization, but I'm not sure how this coincides with the intuitive definition. I'm not even sure how the naturality condition would say that $g$ and $\alpha_X(g)$ even have the same endpoints.

And to tackle the main question, would it be the right approach to consider the forgestful functor from Top to Set?

Thanks!

Comment: The motivation for "reparameterization" comes from the fact that natural automorphisms on $\mathrm{Path}$ correspond to homeomorphisms on $I$, which are reparameterizations of paths in the obvious sense. That $\alpha_X(g)$ and $g$ have the same endpoints is a consequence of $\mathrm{Path}$'s representability, that every $\alpha$ comes from a homeomorphism $I\to I$; naturality of $\alpha$ is not sufficient by itself to make that hold.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine, thanks for your insight. Hatcher defines re-parametrization to be composition with continuous $f: I \rightarrow I$, rather than homeomorphism, but  I assume this is just difference in definition, as what Hatcher is doing would amount to saying the natural transformation, rather than natural isomorphism are re-parametrization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Yoneda, each natural transformation $\alpha:\textbf{Path}\to\textbf{Path}$
is induced by a map $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ in $\textbf{Top}$, that is a continuous map.
Then $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism iff $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

So take $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ to be a homeomorphism. The corresponding $\alpha$
takes a path $p:[0,1]\to X$ to the path $p_1=p\circ\phi$, that is
$$p_1(t)=p(\phi(t)).$$

Comment: thanks, helped a lot!